# Programmatically add label to grid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, wpf-controls

Hey all i am trying to add a label to my grid using the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim dynamicLabel As New Label()
  Dim g As New Grid

  dynamicLabel.Name = "NewLabel"
  dynamicLabel.Content = "TEST"
  dynamicLabel.Width = 240
  dynamicLabel.Height = 30
  dynamicLabel.Margin = New Thickness(0, 21, 0, 0)
  dynamicLabel.Foreground = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.White)
  dynamicLabel.Background = New SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)

  Grid.SetRow(dynamicLabel, 0)
  Grid.SetColumn(dynamicLabel, 6)
  g.Children.Add(dynamicLabel)
End Sub
```

However, i never see anything on the grid after i push the button... what am i missing?

Comment: How many columns do you have? In `Grid.SetColumn` you add Label to column 50.

Comment: @LPL i only have 7 labels inside the grid right now. I've tried replaceing the *50* with *8* and it still did not show.

Comment: But how many columns you have defined in `Grid.ColumnDefinitions`? btw: column index is zero based.

Comment: @LPL only has 1 it seems. Just displays **<ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />** within **<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>**

Comment: I wasn't sure about non posted code. But then I agree with @H.B.

Comment: @LPL updated OP with new code.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I corrected this by naming the other grid. I never had the grid named and therefore thats why the **.Children.Add** never would add to the grid. I tried **mainGrid.Children.Add**  (mainGrid is the name of my parent grid) and it would always throw an error because it was the grid *inside* that it was needing for this part.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) //Handles Button1.Click
  Dim dynamicLabel As new Label();

  dynamicLabel.Name = "NewLabel";
  dynamicLabel.Content = "TEST";
  dynamicLabel.Width = 240;
  dynamicLabel.Height = 30;
  dynamicLabel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 21, 0, 0);
  dynamicLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
  dynamicLabel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

  Grid.SetRow(dynamicLabel, 0);
  Grid.SetColumn(dynamicLabel, 0);
  childGrid.Children.Add(dynamicLabel); //'<-changed to grid name in XAML properties
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add a button or a Label (just change Button to Label) to a Grid, you can use this:

```
internal void FillbtnSubCat(Grid grid)
    {
        var myDefinition = new ColumnDefinition();

        var myButton = new Button();

        Grid.SetColumn(myButton, count);

        myButton.Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 5, 25);
        myButton.MinWidth = 30;
        myButton.Content = count;

        myButton.Click+= new RoutedEventHandler(Click1);

        myDefinition.Width = new GridLength(68);

        grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(myDefinition);

        grid.Children.Add(myButton);
        count++;
    }


void Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myButton = sender as Button;
        MessageBox.Show(myButton.GetHashCode().ToString());
    }
```

and XAML

```
 <ListView Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,10,5,5" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <Grid Name="Grid1" Height="100" Width="auto">

            </Grid>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

gride is the name of my gride in dynamicForm.xaml window.
 it creates button and add to gride, then in button click evnt it creates a label by clicking on a  the button.

```
  public partial class DynamicForm : Window
    {

    Label lb = new Label();


  public DynamicForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Button dynamicButton = new Button();
        dynamicButton.Content = "Click me";
        Grid.SetRow(dynamicButton, 0);
        Grid.SetColumn(dynamicButton, 0);

        gride.Children.Add(dynamicButton);

        dynamicButton.Click += button1_Click;


    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


       Label dynamicLabel = new Label();

       dynamicLabel.Name = "NewLabel";
       dynamicLabel.Content = "TEST";
       dynamicLabel.Width = 240;
       dynamicLabel.Height = 30;
       dynamicLabel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 21, 0, 0);
       dynamicLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
       dynamicLabel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

       Grid.SetRow(dynamicLabel, 1);
       Grid.SetColumn(dynamicLabel, 0);

      gride.Children.Add(dynamicLabel);


    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the shown code you never add the new grid to any window/control in a window.

Comment: @StealthRT: *This needs no code example.* You create a grid but don't seem to do anything with it, why should anything happen?

Comment: No, the *code* would be to **show me how to add to the window/control**. Not just telling me.

Comment: @StealthRT: You added the label to the grid, that's adding a control to another control. Just do the same with the grid, add it as a child to another control that is already in the window. Also you probably should not be doing this in the first place.