# CefSharp ChromiumWebBrowser - not displayed/rendered

Tags: c#, wpf, chromium, cefsharp

I have a simple application, a `Grid` with a `ChromiumWebBrowser` inside. When I create the `ChromiumWebBrowser` in XAML, it works. But when I create it from the code-behind and add it to the grid, it doesn't show up - I just get the Grid's black background.

```
<!--This works-->
<Grid Name="gRight" Background="Black">
    <cefSharp:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="cefBrowser" Margin="0,20,0,0"  Address="http://www.google.com" />
</Grid>
```

The code that doesn't work :

```
public Window1()
{
     InitializeComponent();
     bool status =CefSharp.Cef.Initialize();
     ChromiumWebBrowser browse = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
     browse.Load("http://www.google.com");
     browse.Width = 500;
     browse.Height = 500;
     browse.Margin = new Thickness(0,20,0,0);
     gRight.Children.Add(browse); // adding to Grid, it doesn't show up    
}
```

Does anyone know why adding from the code-behind doesn't work in this case ?

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659435/programmatically-add-label-to-grid

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, I've tried adding into different `Grid`'s but never works from code-behind.

Comment: Set Address instead of calling Load

Comment: @amaitland Thanks a lot, setting the Address worked! Does calling Load not work in some circumstances ? Please add as an answer so I can close this question.

Comment: Load does not work when the browser is not onitialized. You can listen the event `IsBrowserInitializedChanged` to know when the browsr is ready.